# icon to indicate technical material

Tags: icons

In a "help" screen, we'd like to display a list of articles from various categories. I'm calling attention to the articles from our official documentation with an icon of a book. We also have a category of articles that are aimed at more technical users or developers. Can you suggest a type of icon that could indicate more technical material (as opposed to material appropriate for the average end user)?

Comment: Is the information specifically development-related? Or is it for a particular industry (e.g. law, medicine, engineering)?

Comment: Good questions.  This is help material for a software package that allows complex configuration, some of which can involve custom coding.  So some of the more technical material talks about code, some talks about configuration details. The industry, for the whole package, is higher education, but the material in the "technical" section isn't more technical in the sense of needing more industry knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your users are developers, perhaps a mini console icon. Talks to their profession (coding in terminal, familiar to look at etc)

[Here is some examples of what I mean.](http://www.freepik.com/index.php?goto=2&searchform=1&k=code)

Comment: I agree with @philip's idea. [The Noun Project](https://thenounproject.com/) is also a great resource for icons. [Here are some developer/console-type icons](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=developer).

Comment: thanks, those are great. I like that developers wear glasses.  (I wear glasses.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what "[For Dummies](http://www.dummies.com/)" are using in their Books:

[image: Image 1]

([Page from one of their Books](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si1Y8.png))

Maybe It's similar to what you need so you could recreate it

Comment: Welcome to UX.stackexchange. If you can please elaborate on your answer.